# What is the correct way to free output buffer after call to openssl::i2d_X509?

Tags: c, openssl, x509

I want to encode X509 structure into DER bytes. Following source code example from the openssl (version > 0.9.7) [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/i2d_X509.html) I need to do (if I would `i2d_X509` to allocate memory on its own):

```
int len;
unsigned char *buf;

buf = NULL;

len = i2d_X509(x, &buf);

if (len < 0)
    /* error */
```

However, it is not completely clear (but I assume it is needed to call `OPENSSL_free`) from the documentation what is the right way to free memory after I am done with `buf`.

What is the correct way to free `buf`?

Comment: Your assuption looks correct to me.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, hope so. But the behavior is not defined, e.g. it may happen that it would be needed to free buf even if error happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**: `OPENSSL_free` must be used to free `buf`.

**Long answer**:
`IMPLEMENT_ASN1_FUNCTIONS` macro is expanded to definition of `i2d_X509` function. The example below demonstrates that, put following source code into a `source.c`:

```
#include <openssl/asn1t.h>
IMPLEMENT_ASN1_FUNCTIONS(X509)
```

After execution of `gcc -E source.c` the macro is expanded to:

```
X509 *d2i_X509(X509 **a, const unsigned char **in, long len) { return (X509 *)ASN1_item_d2i((ASN1_VALUE **)a, in, len, (&(X509_it))); }
int i2d_X509(X509 *a, unsigned char **out) { return ASN1_item_i2d((ASN1_VALUE *)a, out, (&(X509_it))); }
X509 *X509_new(void) { return (X509 *)ASN1_item_new((&(X509_it))); } 
void X509_free(X509 *a) { ASN1_item_free((ASN1_VALUE *)a, (&(X509_it))); }
```

The point of interest is definition of `i2d_X509`, in turn that function calls `ASN1_item_i2d`. As per source code of openssl, `ASN1_item_i2d` is a function defined in `tasn_enc.c` file:

```
static int asn1_item_flags_i2d(ASN1_VALUE *val, unsigned char **out,
                               const ASN1_ITEM *it, int flags)
{
    if (out && !*out) {
        unsigned char *p, *buf;
        int len;
        len = ASN1_item_ex_i2d(&val, NULL, it, -1, flags);
        if (len <= 0)
            return len;
        buf = OPENSSL_malloc(len);
        if (buf == NULL)
            return -1;
        p = buf;
        ASN1_item_ex_i2d(&val, &p, it, -1, flags);
        *out = buf;
        return len;
    }

    return ASN1_item_ex_i2d(&val, out, it, -1, flags);
}
```

The branch `if (out && !*out)` is used in a case described in the original question (`buf` is `NULL`). So, internally, openssl allocates memory for the `buf` using `OPENSSL_malloc`, and as a consequence `OPENSSL_free` must be used to deallocate memory.

*Note*: I looked at the source code of [openssl](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/4e9954799aaf6a9012603ed35b9168f2001e668d) available on the GH at the current time.